# When did Gus start taunting Hector?

Tags: breaking-bad, better-call-saul

In *Better Call Saul* it seems like Gus started taunting Hector even before Hector could communicate and if so, did he not tip his hand?
In

> Episode 3 season 6 when Nacho says he set up Lalo as he was paid by the Peruvians, Hector hits the bell and points at Fring -- is this not a cause for concern? Hector can even spell things out in a belabored but effective way. It seems that there is no way that Hector can't convey his suspicions but perhaps they already suspect Fring and Hector really has nothing to add.

On the other hand, if Gus started to taunt Hector early, his family would have found out and this alone could have caused problems or simply the nursing facility would have been told not to allow Fring to visit.

Answer (score 6):

It’s no secret that Gus hates Hector. Hector shot Max in the head right next to Gus. No-one thinks that Gus has actually got over that — they only believe that his fear of Don Eladio, and his dependence on him for his drug supply, will keep him from actively moving against Hector.

Similarly, it’s no secret that Hector hates Gus, and has done since Gus’s first attempt to become involved with Eladio. As such, as we see in *Fun and Games*, any accusations by Hector only hold weight with Eladio if they come with evidence of Gus actually working against Hector or the cartel, hence Lalo’s search for proof of the superlab.

As Eladio intimates to Gus, he expects his Dons to kind of hate each other, and him to some extent: these are violent and ruthless criminals, they’re unlikely to get along in a chill fashion. As long as they’re making money and not actively screwing each other over enough to disrupt the money-making, Eladio’s happy.

Comment: +1 - and it's also worth mentioning that Gus *never* taunts Hector when there is anyone around to witness it. Hector never has any way to get a smoking gun on Gus, so his accusations just look like his petty hatred growing out of control as Gus's star rises and his falls with his disability.

Comment: @ruffdove Even when Gus was alone with Hector while Hector was in a coma, Gus still just told him a completely innocent and totally cute story about his childhood pet coati.

Comment: Well yeah, but the subtext of that story would have been *obvious* to an outside observer who knew the two men's history.

Comment: I figured it just meant that Gus really like lemons.

Comment: Ha! That was pretty good.